# How to get position of checkbox in listview

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview

how to get id or position of a checkbox inside listview?
I need to update database when isChecked = true or false, but I need position...
maybe I could just do same things as in OnItemClick method?

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id){


    CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)itemClicked.findViewById(R.id.cbxList);
    cbx.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        }
    });

    if(cbx.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        if(cbx.isChecked()){
            cbx.setChecked(false);
            int cbxID = 0;
            cv.put(DB.CBX, cbxID);
            mDB.updateCbx(cv, id);
            Log.d(LOG, " updated with id = " + id + " and cbxID is " + cbxID);
        }else{
            cbx.setChecked(true);
            int cbxID = 1;
            cv.put(DB.CBX, cbxID);
            mDB.updateCbx(cv, id);
            Log.d(LOG, " updated with id = " + id + " and cbxID is " + cbxID);
        }

    }else{
        Intent intentContactView = new Intent(this, ContactView.class);
        intentContactView.putExtra("id", id);
        startActivity(intentContactView);
    }       
}
```

The method getView() from class with SimpleCursorAdapter... same question, how to get the position or id of chosen checkbox?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbxList);


    }

    return view;
}
```

and my Xml file with listview's items. Here said checkboxes are invisible, but they appears, when I call them (just for understanding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivPhoto"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/imageWidth"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/imageHeight"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:contentDescription="@string/photoDescription"
                android:src="@drawable/default_contact" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSurname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbxList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: u will get so many posts related to same on net, surf a bit

Comment: could you also post the xml layout of your view defining every item of your ListView?

Comment: It appears that you may have to define a custom adapter and manipulate the checkbox events within the getView() method. From the information you have given there is a possibility that your checkbox events are 'clashing' with the click event attached to every list item containing that checkbox. Handling such events within the getView() method of you custom adapter resolve this issue.

Comment: @Richa , unfortunately, I didn't find, but I was looking more than enough...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set tag to the checkbox, and when you get the callback for the event, you can extract the tag from view provided in callback. Set the position in the tag (setTag() is the method for setting tag).
So your stuff should look something like following:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    //...
    CheckBox cbx;
    //...
    cbx.setTag(position);
    cbx.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkListener);
    //...
}

OnCheckedChangeListener checkListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        int position = buttonView.getTag();
    }
};
```

Comment: Would you mind if I edited your answer for formatting? I had the same answer typed up, but you posted first, and I'd be happy to copy/paste my formatted code in.

Comment: it is not working, I tried.. because position which I parsed doesn't move. It is always the same, cuz I didn't click on list's item.

Comment: @Yurets What do you mean exactly? This is a very common way to do this. Have you checked if `position` is correct in `onCheckedChange()`? If so, then something's wrong elsewhere.

Comment: @MikeM. yeah, of course I checked it... "position" stay still whatever checkbox I would choose... maybe is some way to allow me to update datebase with value "1" if checked and with "0" when unchecked?
I mean call again this part of code: int cbxID = 1; // 1 if cheched
            cv.put(DB.CBX, cbxID);
            mDB.updateCbx(cv, id);

Comment: Then it's not getting set correctly in `getView()`. Please post that method.

Comment: @MikeM. in getView same situation :-(

Comment: @MikeM. omg, I'm a looser.... you're right, in getView worked out...greatest thank you to you!!!

Comment: This is a little different than what was posted, but this way you only need one `OnCheckedChangeListener`, instead of instantiating a new one for each `Checkbox`.

Comment: @Yurets here flow is like, just before displaying of row in listview, you get a callback in getView(), in getView you are saying to checkbox that hey checkbox i am tagging you with a position, so whenever you will be clicked i will recognize you by your tag because you all checkboxes looks same. Now when you click a cb, you get a callback, in callback you get a cb, you now say to cb that give me your tag, coz i want to tell db that you have changed your state

Comment: @GauravGupta you're right, I didn't think that way... hm, really good comment, thanks... Just my mind so tired because of that situation (it was a bit widely question), that I thought it will blow up.

Comment: int position = (int) buttonView.getTag();  use this line while getting position

Answer (score 0):

you are using the  onItemClick method of listview adapter the argument position you have passed in it is the position on whihc user has clicked use the value of that variable according to your need.

Comment: it is different positions unfortunately... here needs something to redirect on starting code inside of onItemClick method, if no way to get the position of cbx... it is a child of listview, maybe in that way smb knows something...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try following approach?

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // convertView init and other stuff

    mCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean state = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
            // mCheckBoxStates is an ArrayList<Boolean> that contains current states of checkboxes 
            // (if you need such information somewhere in your app)
            mCheckBoxStates.get(position) = state;
            if (state) {
                // Update your database according to mCheckBoxStates values
            }
        });

    // other stuff

}
```

Comment: it won't work, cuz position is not reachable for method onClick, but good idea, thank you!